# Tradução da medalha Curious

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Essa medalha não se encontra traduzida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão:

> **Curioso**: Fez uma boa pergunta em cinco dias diferentes e as manteve com pontuação positiva.

Comment: boa pergunta == 25+ votos?

Comment: Você poderia postar sua sugestão (e adaptá-la para as outras duas medalhas similares) em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1652/h%c3%a1-tr%c3%aas-medalhas-ainda-n%c3%a3o-traduzidas? Obrigado.

Comment: @bfavaretto um pouco atrasado, mas feito

Comment: Valeu, desculpe a encheção...